# Problems with form and innerHTML on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Yesterday I was making a code that shows in a text content what you write in the form input. I wrote this:

```
<p id="demo">
Show code
</p>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="clo" />
    <button onclick="myFunctionn()">Try it</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        function myFunctionn() {
            var bub = document.getElementById("clo").value
            var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
            var res = str.replace("code", bub);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
</form>
```

The problem with this code is that when you click the button it substitute the text for a few times and then it refreshes the page. How can I fix this?

Comment: remove the form element and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bind a `click` handler. Bind a `submit` handler on the form and prevent the default behavior.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="clo" /> <button type="submit">Try it</button>
</form>
<script>
function myFunction(e) {
    var bub = document.getElementById("clo").value
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("code", bub);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    e.preventDefault();
}
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', myFunction, false);
//and keep your JS out of your HTML
</script>
```

This has the advantage of being accessible, and allowing functionality such as implicit submission when a user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the text field is focused.

Answer (score 0):

Add `type="button"` to your button. The default type of a button is `submit`, so it's submitting your form to the server, which refreshes the page. Non-submit buttons don't cause a form submission, so only the Javascript will be executed.